# mysqli data insert not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a simple MySQL connection to insert data. The connection is fine, but when I submit the form data, the `INSERT` is not working. But if I put manual data into the query, it works fine.

```
<form action="dbconnection.php" method="POST">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required=""/>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>

<?php
print_r($_POST);
$server = "localhost";
$dbname="mytestdb";
$username = "root";
$password= "";

//create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$dbname);


//check connection

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed". $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "connected successfull";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user('username','password') VALUES ($username,$password)";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: How does it fail?  Check for any errors returned from the database, it could very well be telling you what the problem is.  Note also that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.  So technically that query could be doing *anything* that your users want it to do.

Comment: What do you think code isn't working? Do you getting any error messages.

Comment: I got it.... thks every one  query shouldbe    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."')";

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes around your column names. Change the ' to `

Comment: that isn't the only problem with their code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes but that's the cause of the error they are getting which they are trying to solve.